# A strange sum over bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-combinatorics, generating-functions, enumerative-combinatorics

While mucking around with some generating functions related to enumeration of regular bipartite graphs, I stumbled across the following cutie.  I wonder if anyone has seen it before, and/or if anyone sees a nice interpretation.  The sum is over all simple bipartite graphs $G$ with $n$ vertices on each side, the product is over all $2n$ vertices $v$ of $G$ and $d_G(v)$ is the degree of vertex $v$ in graph $G$.
$$\sum_{G\subseteq K_{n,n}} ~ \prod_{v\in V(G)} (n-2d_G(v)) = 2^{n^2}n!~.\kern 3cm (1)$$

**Addition 1, proof.**  Consider $n^2$ commuting indeterminates $\{x_{ij}\}_{i,j=1\ldots n}$. The polynomial
$$P(\boldsymbol{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n x_{i,j} \times \prod_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i,j}.$$
has terms with each variable having power 0, 1 or 2. Consider the total coefficient $C~$ of the terms with only even powers.  One way is to sum each variable over $\pm 1$, which makes the terms we don't want cancel out and the others get multiplied by $2^{n^2}$. This gives (1), interpreting $G$ as the bipartite graph whose edges are the variables with value $-1$.  Alternatively, note that each term has total degree $2n$ and the only possible such term with even degrees is $\prod_{i=1}^n x_{i,\sigma(i)}^2$ for some permutation $\sigma$.  This shows $C=n!~$.

**Addition 2, generalisation.** Define the numbers
$$\rho(n,k,d) = \sum_{j\ge 0} (-1)^j \binom{d}{j} \binom{n-d}{k-j}.$$
Let $k_1,\ldots,k_{2n}$ be a sequence of nonnegative integers.  Then
$$\sum_{G\subseteq K_{n,n}} ~ \prod_{v\in V(G)} \rho(n,k_v,d_G(v)) 
  = 2^{n^2} B(\boldsymbol{k}), $$
where $B(\boldsymbol{k})$ is the number of simple bipartite graphs with vertex $v$ having degree $k_v$ for all $v$.  The case (1) follows from $\rho(n,1,d)=n-2d$. The proof of the general case is similar.

Comment: A little playing with your sum shows that if you replace the appearance of n in the left hand side of your equation by a variable t, the right hand side becomes $2^{n^2}n!L_n(-(t-n)^2)$, with $L_n$ the $n$th Laguerre polynomial. Maybe this has a meaning? $${}$$ Extra points for introducing a $q$ somewhere in the left hand side and getting $q$-Laguerre polynomials on the right hand side!

Comment: An unsuccessful approach is to weigh each summand by the number $e(G)$ of edges in $G$: we get $$\sum_{G\subseteq K_{n,n}} ~ q^{e(g)}\prod_{v\in V(G)} (t-2d_G(v)) = 4^n n! q^n (q+1)^{n^2-2 n} L_n\left(-\frac{((q+1) t-2 n q)^2}{4
   q}\right).$$

Comment: (It is cute, though, how $2n$ of the factors of $2$ in the formula without the $q$s stay $2$s, while the other $n^2-2n$ become $(1+q)$s...)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the average value of the product (I don't have the number of summands readily available, and you (@Brendan) probably do...)

Comment: The number of summands is $2^{n^2}$, as there are $n^2$ edges in the complete bipartite graph, and we are summing over its subsets.

Comment: So, the statement is that the expected value of the product is $n!.$ I find it really hard to believe that there is not a a simple way to see this (on the other hand, I am not seeing it right now :()


Comment: Ah, I see @Kevin proved the exact thing in the answer...

Comment: @Mariano: Nice observations!  

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right interpretation or not...it may really just be another way of encoding the generating function argument.  Let $H$ be a random bipartite graph where every edge appears independently with probability $1/2$.  Then the left hand side is 
$$2^{n^2} E \left(\prod_v f(v) \right),$$
where $f(v)$ is equal to $\sum_u x(u,v)$ and $x(u,v)$ is $1$ if an edge is not present, $-1$ if an edge is present.  Expanding out the product and using linearity of expectation, we can write this as

$$2^{n^2} \sum_{\sigma} E \left(\prod_{v} x(v,\sigma(v))\right)$$
Where $\sigma$ consists of all mappings taking each vertex to a vertex on the opposite side.

Any $\sigma$ for which some edge $(v,\sigma(v))$ appears only once has $0$ expectation due to independence.  The $\sigma$ for which every edge appears for both of its endpoints correspond to matchings between the left and right side, of which there are $n!$.  (This last observation corresponds to the fact that the expected square of the permanent of an $n \times n$ random Bernoulli matrix is $n!$...I think it goes at least back to Turan).

Comment: That's great.  I'll add my proof in a few hours; you will see that it is somewhat parallel to yours.  There is a nice generalization that I'll give too.